# In Excel, how can I create a table which has a start date and end date with the unique value next to it from a list of dates with values?

Tags: excel, date, range, unique, repeat

I have multiple very large table's in Excel which are similar to this (all the tables have the same repeating value in a particular date range):

[image]

I would like to create other tables from this which have a start date and end date with the unique value next to it.

Using the example above - I would want to get the following:

[image]

I'm struggling to find a way to do this. Am I missing a trick somewhere?

I was wondering whether anyone can help me out with this/ has useful advice?

Thank you.

Comment: A pivot table should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I've tried a pivot and can't seem to get 2 columns (start and end date) from 1 column date. Do you know how I would go about it?

Comment: you would add date twice to the values and make one the min and the other the max.  Dates are just numbers to Excel.  You will then need to format the output as a date, as Excel will put in the base double number.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Could you share an image/ example to help explain please? I'm having a go adding on the above example I provided and am getting the same number for all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Pivot table.

Put the date in values twice and change one to the Min and the other to the max then format the output as dates:

[image]